# Does anyone understand this error?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

> ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "2015-01-31:00:00" at position 10

I am trying to call `np.datetime64('2015-01-31:00:00')`.

Comment: Weird format. Shouldn't there be a space between date and time?

Comment: '2015-01-31T00:00'

Answer (score 3):

A date in `ms` gives an idea of the string format it accepts

```
In [74]: np.datetime64('2015-01-31','ms')
Out[74]: numpy.datetime64('2015-01-31T00:00:00.000')
```

See also the examples on the `numpy` doc page

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Space also works

```
In [79]: np.datetime64('2015-01-31 00:00:00','ms')
Out[79]: numpy.datetime64('2015-01-31T00:00:00.000')
```